# Solve an Integral-differential equation with DSolve

Tags: differential-equations, integral-equations

I do not understand why the following code does not solve the equation:

[image: equation]

```
ClearAll
eqn = y[t] == \!\(
\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(\[Integral]\), \(0\), \(t\)]\(Exp[
      a \((t - s)\)] y[s] \[DifferentialD]s\)\);
sol = DSolve[eqn, y[t], t, y[0] = 1]
```

Can someone help me please?
Thanks in advance.

I tried to use yours idea on the real case, obtaining the following, which is still an integral-differential equation:

[image: eq]

Comment: `DSolve[]'s` support for integral equations is still somewhat limited,
 so don't be surprised if some things don't work yet

Comment: Are there some other functions which could be useful?

Comment: Use `LaplaceTransform` for equation.

Answer (score 2):

You can sometimes remove the integral part by differentiating the expression with respect to $t$.  For example,

```
D[y[t] == Integrate[Exp[a*(t - s)]*y[s], {s, 0, t}], t]
(*y'[t] == Integrate[a*E^(a*(-s + t))*y[s], {s, 0, t}] + y[t] *)
```

We see that the first term on the right hand side is simply $ay(t)$.  So, now you can solve the differential equation

$$y'(t)=(a+1)y(t)$$

Or

```
DSolve[{y'[t] == (a + 1) y[t], y[0] == 1}, y[t], t]
(* {{y[t] -> E^(t + a t)}} *)
```

Comment: I agree with you, the fact is that I was looking for solving a more difficult integral equation, which related differential equation still presents integrals which I cannot neglect.

Comment: To clarify, I did not neglect the integral.  If your kernel function is separable (i.e., $k(t,s)=f(t)g(s)$), then the following relation should hold upon differentiation `y'[t] == y[t] (f[t] g[t] + f'[t]/f[t])`.  No integrals are necessary.  If it is not separable, then, as Mariusz stated, your options are probably limited, but you would need to provide an example to be sure.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I get your idea. I tried to apply it on the real case, obtaining the differential-integral equation above

Comment: You should provide the initial definition for $y(t)$ and $K(t-s)$.  It will be easier for people to help if you also provide the _Mathematica_ code.